# Apache Java Configuration API - configuration profiles (inheritance)?

Tags: java, properties, apache-commons-config

When i was working with Zend Framework, I used to have `.ini` configuration files, where I could do this:

```
[production]
setting1 = abc
setting2 = def

[development : production]
setting1 = ghi
```

And when I turned on the `development` application profile then the `setting1` had a value of `ghi`, whereas in the prdouction mode it was `abc`. Is is possible to define such inherited settings in Apache Commons Configuration?

I know that I can define multiple configuration files and create a [CompositeConfiuration](http://commons.apache.org/configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/CompositeConfiguration.html) from them, but how to tell the application that it should include only specific files in different modes? I do not also have an idea how to set these application profiles yet but another setting called `PROFILE` should do the work for me.

If possible, I would not want to split the settings in multiple files.

I can't find any information about how this should be done in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Configuration reads the config options from a file into a memory data structure. Besides variable expansion, there is no further post processing by default. So your options are:

- Put all options in a default config and then use individual "delta" configs that overwrite the defaults. Merge these individual files with `CompositeConfiuration`.

  This design follows Java's inheritance model: Base type which you extend to overwrite some value and add new ones.
- Create a post processor that takes the huge config and turns that into a new config with your preferred merging rules applied.
- Create a helper object to look up values by key in the config. That would allow you do the merging at lookup time.